# Return list of names from fact

Tags: prolog

I'm learning prolog and I'm trying to return a list of names from the declarations I've done.

Example:

```
person(sam). 
person(tom). 
person(holly).
```

I want to return the names of anyone declared in person. I tried doing this:

```
people([]).
people([X | XS]) :-
    person(X),
    people(XS).
```

It works, kind of, it adds `sam` to the list, then adds `sam` infinitely rather than switching to `tom`, then `holly` and then ending. Could anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: @CommuSoft shows you options for how to do this. The reason why what you have doesn't work is because Prolog starts from the beginning of the facts when a new predicate clause call is entered. So with each recursive call to `people`, that starts from the beginning of the facts again. That's why `findall/3` exists. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Custom implementation

You can solve this for instance by using a [`member/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=member/2) and an accumulator:

```
people(L) :-
    people([],L).
people(L,[X|R]) :-
    person(X),
    \+member(X,L),
    people([X|L],R).
people(L,[]) :-
    \+ (person(X),\+ member(X,L)).
```

Or if you know how to work with *cut* (`!`), you can use [@CapelliC's version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34274882/return-list-of-names-from-fact/34275162?noredirect=1#comment56295142_34275162):

```
people(L) :-
    people([],L).
people(L,[X|R]) :-
    person(X),
    \+member(X,L),
    !,
    people([X|L],R).
people(L,L).
```

So each time you look for a `person/1` `X` such that it is not a member of `L`. In case you cannot find such person anymore, the last clause is selected. In that case the empty list `[]` is propagated backwards, and for each element on the call stack, the specific `X` is added in the front.

## Using the `findall/3` builtin

Prolog variants that follow the ISO standards have however a builtin [`findall/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3):

```
findall(+Template, :Goal, -Bag)
```

You use it as follows:

- The `Template` is a functor (this can be a variable) of data you wish to obtain, here `X`;
- the `Goal` is a predicate (or a list of predicates, etc.) that should be satisfied. Prolog will, internally, call the `Goal`; and
- `Bag` is the output: a list of results.

If you use this like:

```
people(L) :-
    findall(X,person(X),L).
```

it will generate a list of all `person/1`s:

```
?- findall(X,person(X),L).
L = [sam, tom, holly].
```

There are other higher order predicates that guarantee uniqueness, etc.

## Semantical difference

Note that `findall/3` and our own `people/1` approach are not semantically equivalent. Indeed, if your database contains a person twice, it will be twice in the bag of `findall/3`. Furthermore our own `people/1` will enumerate lists in every possible order.

Comment: @CapelliC: using a cut `!` in the previous clause?

Comment: Really helped me understand with the explanations too, thanks a lot!

Comment: here is the code I tested: `people(L,R) :-
    person(X),
    \+member(X,L),
    !, people([X|L],R).
people(L,L).
`

Comment: @CapelliC: usually I would have adviced the same, but since cuts have side effects when it comes do multidirectional predicates, I start using them less often. I've included your version in the answer (with a reference to the comment of course).